# 301 Redirect all K2 Items (or Joomla! articles) to the Parent Category

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, k2, seo, category

I have a [Joomla!](https://www.joomla.org/) + [K2](http://getk2.org/) site that uses categories as main landing pages with articles filling in various sections of the page. Thus, I don't want articles to be seen or indexed by Google individually. However, through the use of a sitemap plugin, Google has been made aware of those individual article links and they have been indexed. Thus, all the SEO weight has been split across the category and the individual articles.

**How can I redirect all articles (K2 items) to their parent categories and keep the link juice?**

My first thought is to add a `header("Location: /[category]",TRUE,301);` to the top of the article template. However, I'm not sure that I can dynamically retrieve the URL of the articles' category like this. Is it possible and, if so, how?

---

Note: This is a large site, so individually adding redirects to `.htaccess` or removing the individual articles URLs from the auto-generated sitemap is not an option.